# Hero section zoomed in on IOS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, styling

#### IOS displays hero images really pixeladed and zoomed in, while other os and browsers other than safari are fine... help!

Not sure how to go about it... Can I fix it through css or just not have a hero slider in the site in order to keep the UX/UI up?

This is my html

```
<section id="hero">
    <div class="container-fluid hero-container">
        <div id="heroCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#heroCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>

                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#heroCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>

                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#heroCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="5000" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/hero/clouds.jpg); background-position: center bottom">
                    <div class="carousel-container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption dark">
                            <div class="hero-content-container">
                                <div class="carousel-header animate__animated animate__fadeInDown">I am an explorer</div>
                                <div class="carousel-content animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-1s">I love to explore and discover new skills, like a new programming language, or a new real language!</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="5000" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/hero/buildings-bottom.jpg); background-position: center bottom">
                    <div class="carousel-container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption dark">
                            <div class="carousel-header animate__animated animate__fadeInDown">I am a problem solver</div>
                            <div class="carousel-content animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-1s">From software and hardware to welding up a new design, I love solving problems that come along with creating</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="5000" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/hero/printer-hero.jpg); background-position: center top">
                    <div class="carousel-container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <div class="carousel-header animate__animated animate__fadeInDown">I love to create</div>
                            <div class="carousel-content animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-1s">Designing and creating new and clever things has been a passion for me all my life</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#heroCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#heroCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="about"></div>
</section>
```

And this is the Css

```
 .hero-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.carousel-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.carousel-item {
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* position: relative; */
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.hero-content-container {
    margin: 0;
}
.carousel-caption {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.dark {
    color: #313131;
}
.carousel-header {
    font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.carousel-content {
    font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .carousel-header {
        font-size: 40px !important;
    }
    .carousel-content {
        font-size: 15px !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .carousel-header {
        font-size: 55px;
    }
    .carousel-content {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
```

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D69n.jpg)

[What it looks like on safari / IOS (apple)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdJ3w.jpg)

Comment: and this is the url (sorry for initally leaving it out): https://thomasandco.xyz/

Comment: forgot to add... on the apple device, it didnt show up correctly on safari or chrome, but on the samsung device + windows computers running chrome + firefox + edge, it works fine

Comment: IOS (some versions) has problems with background-attachment: fixed. This leads to 'pixellated/too stretched' image. Do you need a workaround?

Comment: well, i liked the look of background-attachment: fixed, but after I took it out it seemed to work out...